# How to develop Remember Me Functionality with Angular JS + JWT Authentication using Spring Security 4 + Spring Rest API

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I want to develop **"Remember ME"** functionality with ***Angular JS + JWT Authentication Using Spring Security 4 + Spring Rest API + Hibernate + Maven + Tomcat***.
Because of some code review and business need, I am forced to use JWT method for user authentication and authorization with above mentioned Spring feature,
I searched on Internet for sample projects and application, But I couldnt find any solution?

Most of them doesn't serve my purpose or way complex to understand.

I would like to get a sample project for reference. Or an IDEA to complete this application. I am stuck with it.

Any one please help me.

**Clarification:**
My Login page should have "Remember Me" check-box, I have decided to use Spring Security remember me feature. But later when using Angular JS in client side, **decided I should not use Spring Form tags that provides REMEMBER ME functionality.**

And now I am unable to find example in Internet for this. So Please can any one help in creating an sample application.

**It would be great if any one could help me with a sample application with good coding standard or some URL of sample codes**

This could serve many people who are searching for a good Sample code to do this and enhance upon it.

**Requesting help. I am stuck and have very less time to research things.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what we did on this project:

https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac

The stack is: AngularJS, Spring MVC, Spring Security, Spring Boot and a jwt authentication.

Comment: You saved my day, I will keep yours my reference.